# Python print None

Tags: python, printing, return

I'm having trouble with print None as a value.

Suppose here's my python code:

```
def a(b):
    b = None
    print b

def c(a):
    if a:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

---

```
>>> a(1)
None            # I need this "None" to show.
>>> c(a(1))
None            # I don't want to print out this, but don't know how.
False
```

My problem is I have to "print" the None when only calling function a.

And when I pass function a to function c, I don't want the "None" to print out.

If I type "return None", Python shell will not show "None" for function a. That's why I thought I can only use "print" if I want to show the "None". But when I pass function a to function c, the "None" also gets printed out. Is there a way to only get the result secretly without printing out the "None" in the 2nd function?

I hope my question is making sense.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score -1):

The call `c(a(1))` will execute `a(1)` first and then `c(a(1))`. Since here `a(1)` is not returning **true**, `c(a(1))` will evaluate to **False**.

That's the reason you get following:

```
None
False
```

Try calling the function as `c(a)` this will return as follows:

```
True
```

This happens because `a` has not executed and it is having some value to it.

Hope this helps!